# How to make Apache Drill understand explicit `NULL` in a csv file?

Tags: csv, null, apache-drill

Assume I have this CSV file:

```
a,b
NULL,1
1,2
```

Then I try doing some queries:

```
> SELECT * FROM dfs.`/path/to/foo.csv`;
+-------+----+
|   a   | b  |
+-------+----+
| NULL  | 1  |
| 1     | 2  |
+-------+----+
2 rows selected

> SELECT * FROM dfs.`/path/to/foo.csv` WHERE a is NULL;
+----+----+
| a  | b  |
+----+----+
+----+----+
No rows selected

> SELECT * FROM dfs.`/path/to/foo.csv` WHERE a is NOT NULL;
+-------+----+
|   a   | b  |
+-------+----+
| NULL  | 1  |
| 1     | 2  |
+-------+----+
2 rows selected

> SELECT * FROM dfs.`/path/to/foo.csv` WHERE a > 0;
Error: SYSTEM ERROR: NumberFormatException: NULL

Fragment 0:0
```

It seems Apache Drill is considering `NULL` as a string.

Even if I replace it with an empty string (`sed -i 's/NULL//g' foo.csv`), Apache Drill still thinks those values are not null.

Is there any way to make it consider `NULL` (or empty value) as… well… *null*?

I'm using the latest release version: 1.9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can!

1. Open up the console at http://[your drillbit ip]:8047 and click on
   the "Options" button on the top right hand corner.
2. Find "drill.exec.functions.cast_empty_string_to_null" and set it to true.

Comment: You can also set this configuration from the SQL console with ```ALTER SYSTEM SET `drill.exec.functions.cast_empty_string_to_null` = true;```, but the option is not working in the latest versions (currently v1.4.0), check this issue and a workaround I posted to overcome the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3214?focusedCommentId=16618242&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16618242